# Random line of text using batch

Tags: text, random, batch-file, line

How could one select a random line of text from a text file and set it in a variable to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's yet another approach. It reads the file name from the command line and uses a `FOR /L` loop to get to the calculated line number:

```
@ECHO OFF
FOR /F "" %%I IN ('FIND /C /V "" ^<%1') DO SET /A lines=%%I
SET /A skip=%RANDOM%%%lines
<%1 (
  FOR /L %%I IN (1,1,%skip%) DO (
    SET /P line=
  )
  SET line=
  SET /P line=
)
ECHO(%line%
```

The `FOR /F` loop simply gets the number of lines in the file (the method is borrowed from [@Aacini's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13355038/297408)).

A rather simplistic formula then calculates the number of lines to skip in the file.

Next, the file is read. The `FOR /L` loop merely consumes the specified number of lines using a `SET /P` instruction. Following the loop, one more `SET /P` command reads the line that is eventually ECHOed.

The above implementation is just to show the basic idea. It is not without issues, but some of them could easily be resolved:

1. There's no testing whether the parameter is indeed supplied. If it is absent, the script will break. You could add the necessary check at the beginning of the script like this:

   ```
   IF "%~1"=="" GOTO :EOF
   ```

   If there's no parameter, this command terminates the script by sending the control to the end of the script (`GOTO :EOF`).
2. The file specified might not exist. Again, you could test that at the beginning, just after verifying that the parameter is supplied, to terminate the script if necessary:

   ```
   IF NOT EXIST %1 GOTO :EOF
   ```
3. If the file is empty, the `lines` will be `0` and the subsequent expression using it will run into a division by zero error. Therefore, you'll also need to test the resulting line count (and prevent the script from running further if the count is indeed 0). You can do that by adding the following line just after the `FOR /F` loop:

   ```
   IF %lines%==0 GOTO :EOF
   ```
4. Like I said, the formula is somewhat simplistic. It doesn't produce a number greater than 32767, which is the limitation of `%RANDOM%`. That might well be enough for you, but in case it is not, you could extend the range to 2<sup>30</sup>-1 using *two* `%RANDOM%` calls like this:

   ```
   SET /A skip=(%RANDOM%*32768+%RANDOM%)%%lines
   ```

So, here's the same script again, amended to address the above mentioned issues:

```
@ECHO OFF
IF "%~1"=="" GOTO :EOF
IF NOT EXIST %1 GOTO :EOF
FOR /F "" %%I IN ('FIND /C /V "" ^<%1') DO SET /A lines=%%I
IF %lines%==0 GOTO :EOF
SET /A skip=(%RANDOM%*32768+%RANDOM%)%%lines
<%1 (
  FOR /L %%I IN (1,1,%skip%) DO (
    SET /P line=
  )
  SET line=
  SET /P line=
)
ECHO(%line%
```

One other note is that, if you like, you can add messages explaining the reason for the premature termination of the script. Basically, wherever you want to add the message, you'll just need to replace the single

```
GOTO :EOF
```

with

```
(ECHO your message & GOTO :EOF)
```

For instance:

```
IF NOT EXIST %1 (ECHO Error! File not found & GOTO :EOF)
```

Answer (score 3):

The Batch program below is Eitan's solution slightly modified to run faster:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set INPUT_FILE="test.txt"

:: # Count the number of lines in the text file and generate a random number
for /f "usebackq" %%a in (`find /V /C "" ^< %INPUT_FILE%`) do set lines=%%a
set /a randnum=%RANDOM% * lines / 32768 + 1, skiplines=randnum-1

:: # Extract the line from the file
set skip=
if %skiplines% gtr 0 set skip=skip=%skiplines%
for /f "usebackq %skip% delims=" %%a in (%INPUT_FILE%) do set "randline=%%a" & goto continue
:continue

echo Line #%randnum% is:
echo/!randline!
```

Comment: +1: Using the `for` loop built-in option to skip lines. Nice.

Comment: The idea of using the `FOR /F "skip="` feature is great, as is the method of getting the line count. But for some reason, when I tested this script on my Windows 7 HP SP1 machine, the numbers generated were always 30000+. It seems strange, because when I test `echo %random%` from the command line, I get *much* more diverse numbers. Anyway, since I used a rather small file in my tests, the `randnum` always ended up being the last line number in the file, due to the big `%RANDOM%` values.

Comment: I tested it again, and it again resulted in the same line number, but a different one (because the random numbers were again generated in a rather close range). Don't know what's happening. The idea is clear, however, and should work perfectly fine, and I have no scruples upvoting your answer even if for the `FIND /V /C ""` alone.

Answer (score 2):

Like it is already mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5777400/how-to-use-random-in-batch-script) in StackOverflow, among others, `%RANDOM%` expands to a random number between 0 and 32767.

You can use this mechanism to generate a random line number. However, to make it a valid line number you will have to normalize it by the the number of lines in the input text file.

Here's a simple script that shows how to do it:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set INPUT_FILE="test.txt"

:: # Count the number of lines in the text file and generate a random number
set lines=0
for /f "usebackq" %%a in (%INPUT_FILE%) do set /a lines+=1
echo %RANDOM% >nul
set /a randnum=%RANDOM% * !lines! / 32768 + 1

:: # Extract the line from the file
set lines=0
for /f "usebackq tokens=*" %%a in (%INPUT_FILE%) do (
    set /a lines+=1
    if !lines!==!randnum! set randline=%%a
)

echo Line #!randnum! is:
echo.!randline!
```

Comment: Does the line `echo %RANDOM% >nul` have any purpose?

Comment: @BaliC Strangely, I needed to use `%RANDOM%` once to "jump-start" the batch random number generator... For some strange reason, I always got the same generated line number without it...