# Random option batch file

Tags: batch-file

would it be possible to possibly chose a random option of the 3 sections using this code http://pastebin.com/wN6y63PH  ?:
:responce1
:responce2
:responce3

More Info:

I would like the program to randomly chose one of the options so its different everytime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
set /a "rnd=%RANDOM% * 3 / 32768 + 1"
goto responce%rnd%
```

Here's more info on [generating random numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5777608/1683264) in Windows batch.

Comment: Random number is random.  There's a 33% chance each time that you will get 3.  If you run the script 10 times, if I remember my prob & stats class correctly, there is still a 3.3% chance that you'll roll a 3 all ten rounds.  I guess 3 is your lucky number this evening.