# How to generate a random number between 1 and 100 using batch

Tags: batch-file, random

%random% seems to go in order.

```
@ECHO OFF
SET /A RAND=%RANDOM% %%100
ECHO %RAND%
ECHO.
```

If you keep running this it increments until it reaches 100 and then the number start over. If it were random it would jump around.

```
@ECHO OFF
SET /A RAND=%RANDOM%
ECHO %RAND%
ECHO.
```

Comment: Your first code creates random numbers between 0 and 99, there is no incrementing

Comment: Please show us the real code you are using. What you've posted, other than generating and displaying random numbers 0..99, not 1..100 works perfectly.

Comment: the first code runs fine on my computer, but from 0 to 99

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use random in BATCH script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5777400/how-to-use-random-in-batch-script)

Answer (score 2):

```
SET /A RAND=%RANDOM%%%100+1
```

---

this may work.

Answer (score 1):

If I understoof the question right, here's what you're looking for.

```
echo off
title Number from 1 to 100.
color 0a
cls

:loop
cls
set /a rand=%random% %%101
echo %rand%
pause >nul
goto loop
```

Answer (score -1):

hey if the problem still persists
use this code
this generates a number between a and b
tweak it to your needs

```
@echo off       
color 02  
echo enter value of A  
set  /p a=  
echo.   
echo  enter value of B  
set /p b=   
:main  
set no=%random%  
if  %no% GEQ %a% goto sub  
if not %no% GEQ %a% goto  main  
:sub  
if %no% LEQ  %b% goto end  
if not %no% LEQ  %b% goto  main  
:end  
echo %no%   
goto main
```

Comment: Since `%Random%` generates numbers between 0 and 32768 your approach is very ineffective and doesn't answer the question