# Number Generator 1-4 | Batch

Tags: batch-file, random

There is an easy way to make a number generator.
But I just want the generated numbers to be 1 - 4

The following program takes too long to get an output

```
@echo off
:RUN
set /a Num=%random%
if %num% LEQ 4 echo %num%
goto :RUN
```

It runs %random% until it gets less than 4, which could be quite a while.

Comment: Look at the output for `for /?` - specifically the section about `for /L`. Or did you want an infinite loop of numbers between 1 and 4?

Comment: `set /a NumBetween1and4=%random% %% 4 + 1`

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use random in BATCH script?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5777400/how-to-use-random-in-batch-script)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can mask the bits in the random value (`And` operation = `&` operator) to retrieve the lower two, getting a number in the range [0,3] and adding 1 to adapt to the indicated range

```
set /a "num=(%random% & 3) + 1"
```

Or, as the random value generated uses 15 bits, it can be shifted to retrieve only the two upper bits

```
set /a "num=(%random% >> 13) + 1"
```

The parenthesis are needed in both cases because `+` operator has higher precedence than `&` or `>>` operators.

You can also use a `Mod` operation (`%` operator) to retrieve the remainder from a division by 4, also getting a number in the range [0,3]

```
set /a "num=%random% %% 4 + 1"
```

The `%` operator (inside batch files the `%` has to be escaped so it becomes `%%`) has higher precedence than the `+` operator, so here parenthesis are not needed.