# Creating an incrementing alphabet sequence

Tags: windows, for-loop, batch-file, cmd

I want to replace an incrementing number for menu items with an alphabet character.

This is my current code:

```bash
:begin
@echo off
if exist "%TEMP%\%~n0.tmp" del "%TEMP%\%~n0.tmp"
SET "order=0"
for /f "Tokens=1*" %%A in ('set ^| find /v "Path="') do call :data %%A

:data
set /a "order+=1"
echo [%order%] %1 >>"%TEMP%\%~n0.tmp"
if %order% GEQ 20 goto :_continue
GOTO :eof

:_continue
cls
type "%TEMP%\%~n0.tmp"
rem set "_choice="
rem choice /c %_choice% /m ">...:"
pause & goto :begin
```

The output is:

```
[1] ALLUSERSPROFILE
[2] APPDATA
[3] CLINK_DIR
etc...
```

I want the output like this:

```
[A] ALLUSERSPROFILE
[B] APPDATA
[C] CLINK_DIR
etc...
```

Comment: Several useful methods [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38000901/loop-through-ascii-codes-in-batch-file)

Comment: The obvious question, based upon the fact that a default Windows installation has more environment variables than there are letters in the alphabet, _(even with `Path` omitted)_, is what are you intending to assign to the variable names beyond the twenty-sixth result from `set | find /v "Path="`? I know your own answer appears to limit the results to fifteen, i.e. `[O]` and then appends `[Z]`, but there seems no reason or explanation for that in the context of your provided command, or question.

Comment: The script just example. The point question is  showing/ adding incrementing  alphabet  in Menu/ Choice. find /v "Path=" is to skip this output.  ['set ^| find /v "Path="] can be replace with another example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created this macro for easy to reuse menu's. simply expand the Menu variable with a list of the options to be selected from as per the example included.

```
@Echo off
    REM Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

======================================================================================
    REM Modular menu macro by T3RRY T3RR0R
        REM https://pastebin.com/K3LpJXh5
        REM to discuss batch macro techniques Join https://discord.gg/HCSEC829F9

    ================================================ REM = Menu macro Definition BEGIN
    REM IMPORTANT - Defines the following Variables:    \n Console_Width Menu*
        REM         Reserved Variable Prefix:           Menu
        REM          - Do not define other variables with the leading name 'Menu' in your
        REM         script to prevent any possibility of variable contamination.

    REM Version Update 24/01/2024
        REM Incorporate ADS redirection + More command to handle cases where 
        REM Menu output exceeds the consoles height and scrolling is disabled.

    REM Version Update 21/01/2024
        REM Variable Structure reworked to minimize variable reservations required by
        REM constraining all internal variables to a single  prefix: menu*
        REM Macro help and usage now embeded in the Macro.
        REM Expanding the macro without arguments will now display the help output.
        REM return variables are now named:
        REM                                 Menu{String}
        REM                                 Menu{Key}
        REM                                 Menu{Number}

    REM Macro definition and expansion environment trickery pioneered by Jeb
        REM Recommended Learning resources: 
        REM https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=9265#p60294
        REM https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=10983&sid=f6937e02068d93bc5a97ef63d4e5319e
        REM Macros with arguments learning resource:
        REM https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=1827

(Set \n=^^^

%= Newline var \n for multi-line macro definition - Do not modify This codeblock. =%)

REM - use REM / remove REM on the below line to enable / disable menu dividing line
    REM Goto :NoDividingLine

    REM Enable DE environment to perform variable concatenation within a for loop
        Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

    REM Get console width for dividing line
    For /f "usebackq tokens=2* delims=: " %%W in (`mode con ^| %__APPDIR__%findstr.exe /LIC:"Columns"`) do Set /A Console_Width=%%W
        Set "Menu_Div=" & For /L %%i in (1 1 %Console_Width%)Do Set "Menu_Div=!Menu_Div!-"
        Endlocal & Set "Menu_Div=%Menu_Div%"

:NoDividingLine
    REM Menu internal variables
    REM keymap. translates literal keypress to the numeric position of the item in the menu list
        Set /a Menu@0=36,Menu@1=1,Menu@2=2,Menu@3=3,Menu@4=4,Menu@5=5,Menu@6=6,Menu@7=7,Menu@8=8,Menu@9=9,Menu@a=10,Menu@b=11,Menu@c=12,Menu@d=13,Menu@e=14,Menu@f=15,Menu@g=16,Menu@h=17,Menu@i=18,Menu@j=19,Menu@k=20,Menu@l=21,Menu@m=22,Menu@n=23,Menu@o=24,Menu@p=25,Menu@q=26,Menu@r=27,Menu@s=28,Menu@t=29,Menu@u=30,Menu@v=31,Menu@w=32,Menu@x=33,Menu@y=34,Menu@z=35
    REM Valid choice characters
        Set "Menu.Keys=123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0"
        Set "Menu.Hash=Header"

REM Menu macro Usage: %Menu% "quoted" "list of" "options"
%= Outer for loop allows environment independant definition =% For /f %%! in ("! ^! ^^^!") Do ^
%= IMPORTANT - No whitespace permitted here =%Set ^"Menu=For %%n in (1 2)Do if %%n==2 (%\n%
    If defined Menu{Args} (%\n%
        %= Switch control via !! Expansion outcome  =%  for /f "tokens=2" %%? in ("%%!%%! 1 0") do (%\n%
        %= Switch - Setlocal / NOP                  =%    If %%~? EQU 1 SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion%\n%
        %= Output Dividing Line                     =%    ^>"%~f0:MenuMacro:$Data" (%\n%
        %= If Header Substitute Output substitution =%    If not "Header" == "%%!Menu.Hash%%!" (%\n%
                                    If Defined Menu_Div Echo(%%!Menu_Div%%!%\n%
                                    Echo(Header%\n%
                                  )%\n%
                                  If Defined Menu_Div Echo(%%!Menu_Div%%!%\n%
        %= Reset Menu.# index for Menu.Item[#]      =%    Set "Menu.#=0"%\n%
        %= Undefine choice command key list         =%    Set "Menu.Chars="%\n%
        %= Redirect output to ADS; For Each in List =%    For %%G in (%%!Menu{Args}%%!)Do (%\n%
        %= For Menu.Item Index value                =%      For %%i in (%%!Menu.#%%!)Do If not %%i GTR 35 (%\n%
        %= Build the Choice key list                =%        Set "Menu.Chars=%%!Menu.Chars%%!%%!Menu.Keys:~%%i,1%%!"%\n%
        %= Define Menu.Item array                   =%        Set "Menu.Item[%%!Menu.Keys:~%%i,1%%!]=%%~G"%\n%
        %= Assign String for safe output            =%        Set "Menu.Output=%%~G"%\n%
        %= Display as [key] Option String           =%        Echo([%%!Menu.Keys:~%%i,1%%!] %%!Menu.Output%%!%\n%
        %= Increment Menu.# Index var               =%        Set /A "Menu.#+=1"%\n%
        %= Close Menu.# expansion loop              =%      )%\n%
        %= Close Menu{Args} String loop             =%    )) %\n%
        %= Read output in from ADS to permit More   =%    More ^< "%~f0:MenuMacro:$Data"%\n%
        %= Output Dividing Line                     =%    If Defined Menu_Div Echo(%%!Menu_Div%%!%\n%
        %= Select option by character index         =%    For /f "delims=" %%o in ('%__APPDIR__%Choice.exe /N /C:%%!Menu.Chars%%!')Do For /f "tokens=1,2 delims=;" %%V in ("%%!Menu.Item[%%o]%%!;%%!Menu@%%o%%!")Do (%\n%
        %= Switch - Endlocal / NOP ; returnVars     =%      ( If %%~? EQU 1 EndLocal ) ^& (%\n%
        %= exit [sub]script w/out modifying option  =%        If /I "%%V" == "Exit" Exit /B 2%\n%
        %= Assign 'Menu{String}' w/literal string   =%        Set "Menu{String}=%%V"%\n%
        %= Assign 'Menu{key}' with key pressed      =%        Set "Menu{Key}=%%o"%\n%
        %= Assign 'Menu{Number} with list position  =%        Set "Menu{Number}=%%~W"%\n%
        %= Reset Menu Argument variable             =%        Set "Menu{Args}="%\n%
        %= Set errorlevel to match Menu{Number}     =%        CMD /C Exit %%~W%\n%
        %= Close Menu macro processing loops        =%  )  )  )%\n%
    )Else (%\n: Show Macro Help if no arguments supplied - will not display if expanded menu variable has trailing whitespace =%
        CLS%\n%
        Echo(Usage:%\n%
        Echo(%\n%
        Echo(%%Menu%%%\n%
        Echo(       Output this help info, Set Errorlevel 0%\n%
        Echo(%\n%
        Echo(%%Menu%% "DoubleQuoted List" "Of Options"%\n%
        Echo(       Output the Menu list, Take input%\n%
        Echo(%\n%
        Echo(%%Menu:Header=Your Custom Header%% "DoubleQuoted List" "Of Options"%\n%
        Echo(       Outputs substituted Header, Output Menu list; Take input%\n%
        Echo(%\n%
        Echo(Return Variables:%\n%
        Echo(       Menu{String}    : The literal String%\n%
        Echo(       Menu{Key}   : The Key Pressed%\n%
        Echo(       Menu{Number}    : The list position of the option as an Integer%\n%
        Echo(                 IE:   Option 1 = 1, Option A = 10%\n%
        Echo(                 Note: The Errorlevel is also set to this value%\n%
        Echo(%\n%
        Echo(  Note:      The number of options available is limited to 36.%\n%
        Echo(%\n%
        Echo(  Important: The following variable prefix is reserved: Menu%\n%
        Echo(%\n%
        Pause%\n%
        CLS%\n%
        %= If Menu expanded without Args Set Errorlevel 0 =%(Call )%\n%
    )%\n%
%= Capture Macro input - Options List       =%)Else Set Menu{Args}=^"
========================================== REM = Menu Macro Definition END

REM Below lines Not required if macro definition is pasted within another script
    REM Load macro from a calling script using any arg within the Findstr Search strings below; Return to caller
    If Not "%~1" == "" Echo(%*|%SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /LI "/D Def Menu Load Menu Get" 2>&1 > nul && Exit /b 0

REM Below lines Are Demo Only.
    REM Everything from this line and below is example usage only.
    REM demonstrates retention of last option variables upon selection of exit
    REM Call:DemoMenu
    REM Echo(You last chose %Menu{String}% by pressing %Menu{Key}% at index %Menu{Number}%
    REM Exit /b 0

    REM view macro usage by expanding without arguments
    %Menu%

    REM Apply Header using substring when expanding macro
    %Menu:Header=This is a demo Header% "See next demo" "Close after seeing this demo's output"
    Echo(You Pressed %Menu{key}% to Choose '%Menu{String}%'; option number = %Menu{Number}%
    If %Menu{Number}% EQU 2 Exit /b 0
    Pause

:DemoMenu
    CLS

    %Menu% List of your Options here. "Double qoute" "Delimited Strings" filler to extend option count. caps at 36 \ / \ / \ / \ / \ / \ / \ / \ / \ / \ . Exit \ . 
    Echo(You Pressed %Menu{key}% to Choose '%Menu{String}%'; option number = %Errorlevel%
    Pause
    Goto:DemoMenu
```

Comment: Awasome! This is advanced professional menu

Comment: I ask based on your script. How to directly display all menu without showing -- More  -- ?

Comment: More will only display if the output exceeds the console height. This ensures the end user will always see all options before making their choice. If you want to remove that feature, remove the line containing `^>"%~f0:MenuMacro:$Data" (%\n%`, the line containing: 
`More ^< "%~f0:MenuMacro:$Data"%\n%`, and one of the closing parentheses in the line immediately prior.

Answer (score 0):

Just share My adapted script from [@T3RR0R](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12343998/t3rr0r) used to Boot Menu. Thanks to him.

> Quic Boot Menu

```
@Echo off
call :MacroMenu
call :GetBootMenu

:QuickBoot
CLS
rem echo *** %~n0 ***
%Menu% %FWOS% %WIOS% %Other% Exit
if /i %Menu{Number}% GTR %cwi% (call :OtherBoot) else (call :BootOS)
rem Echo(You Pressed %Menu{key}% to Choose '%Menu{String}%'; option number = %Errorlevel%: %Menu{Number}%
Goto:QuickBoot
:: #### END OF QuickBoot ####
======================================================================================

:GetBootMenu
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET "numbfw=1" &rem start number 1
set "_fwos=bcdedit /enum firmware ^| findstr "des" ^| findstr /v "PCI CD Setup Splash FDD Windows""
for /f "Tokens=2-6" %%A in ('%_fwos%') do set "fw=!fw!"%%A %%B %%C %%D %%E" "& set /a "numbfw+=1"
SET "numbwi=%numbfw%" &rem start number= continue numbfw
set "_wios=bcdedit /enum osloader ^| findstr "des" ^| find /v "Recovery""
for /f "Tokens=2-6" %%A in ('%_wios%') do set "wi=!wi!"%%A %%B %%C %%D %%E" "& set /a "numbwi+=1"
Endlocal & set "FWOS=%fw%"& set "WIOS=%wi%"& set /a "cfw=%numbfw% - 1"& set /a "cwi=%numbwi% - 1"
set "Other=ReOpen ReBoot ShutDown A.Startup Bios SafeMode"
exit /b

:BootOS
for /f "tokens=1-2" %%D in ('echo %Menu{String}%') do set "DE=%%D %%E"
if /i %Menu{Number}% LEQ %cfw% (set "store=firmware") else (set "store=osloader")
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /F "usebackq tokens=1-3" %%a in (`bcdedit /enum %store% ^| findstr "den des"`) DO (
    if /I "%%a"=="identifier" set "ID=%%b"
    if /I "%%b %%c"=="!DE!"   set "F_ID=!ID!"
)
EndLocal & set "ID=%F_ID%"

if /I "%ID%"=="" (echo.& echo   FW/OS Not Found& timeout 2 >nul & exit /b)
if /I "%DE%"=="USB HDD:" call :USBCheck
echo.
rem echo    Boot to %Menu{String}%^?
rem echo    %ID%
rem set Opt=
rem set /p Opt=".   X=Cancel | Enter=Boot :"
rem if /I "%Opt%"=="x" exit /b
if /i %Menu{Number}% LEQ %cfw% ( bcdedit /set {fwbootmgr} bootsequence %ID%
) else                ( bcdedit /bootsequence %ID% )
shutdown /r /t 00 &exit

:OtherBoot
set "MS=%Menu{String}%"
if /i "%MS%"=="Bios"        shutdown /r /fw /t 00   &exit
if /i "%MS%"=="ReBoot"      shutdown /r /t 00       &exit
if /i "%MS%"=="A.Startup"   shutdown /r /o /f /t 00 &exit
if /i "%MS%"=="ShutDown"    shutdown /s /t 00       &exit
if /i "%MS%"=="ReOpen"      start %~nx0             &exit
if /i "%MS%"=="SafeMode"    call :SafeMode
exit /b

:SafeMode
wmic computersystem get BootupState | Find "Normal" >nul || call :ExitSafeB
bcdedit /set {current} safeboot minimal && call :BootS
    :ExitSafeB
bcdedit /enum {current} | Find "safeboot" >nul && bcdedit /deletevalue {current} safeboot
    :BootS
bcdedit /bootsequence {current}& shutdown /r /t 00& exit

:USBCheck
wmic diskdrive where InterfaceType='USB' get InterfaceType 2> nul | Find "USB" >nul || (
echo    insert an USB Drive first &timeout 3 >nul & goto :QuickBoot)


rem  ########## THIS IS FROM SOURCE ##################### 
:MacroMenu
@Echo off
======================================================================================
    REM Modular menu macro by T3RRY T3RR0R
    REM https://pastebin.com/K3LpJXh5
    REM Version Update 24/01/2024
    ================================================ REM = Menu macro Definition BEGIN

(Set \n=^^^

%= Newline var \n for multi-line macro definition - Do not modify This codeblock. =%)

    Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    For /f "usebackq tokens=2* delims=: " %%W in (`mode con ^| %__APPDIR__%findstr.exe /LIC:"Columns"`) do Set /A Console_Width=%%W
        Set "Menu_Div=" & For /L %%i in (1 1 %Console_Width%)Do Set "Menu_Div=!Menu_Div!-"
        Endlocal & Set "Menu_Div=%Menu_Div%"

:NoDividingLine
    REM Menu internal variables
    REM keymap. translates literal keypress to the numeric position of the item in the menu list
        Set /a Menu@0=36,Menu@1=1,Menu@2=2,Menu@3=3,Menu@4=4,Menu@5=5,Menu@6=6,Menu@7=7,Menu@8=8,Menu@9=9,Menu@a=10,Menu@b=11,Menu@c=12,Menu@d=13,Menu@e=14,Menu@f=15,Menu@g=16,Menu@h=17,Menu@i=18,Menu@j=19,Menu@k=20,Menu@l=21,Menu@m=22,Menu@n=23,Menu@o=24,Menu@p=25,Menu@q=26,Menu@r=27,Menu@s=28,Menu@t=29,Menu@u=30,Menu@v=31,Menu@w=32,Menu@x=33,Menu@y=34,Menu@z=35
    REM Valid choice characters
        Set "Menu.Keys=123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0"
        Set "Menu.Hash=Header"

REM Menu macro Usage: %Menu% "quoted" "list of" "options"
%= Outer for loop allows environment independant definition =% For /f %%! in ("! ^! ^^^!") Do ^
%= IMPORTANT - No whitespace permitted here =%Set ^"Menu=For %%n in (1 2)Do if %%n==2 (%\n%
    If defined Menu{Args} (%\n%
        %= Switch control via !! Expansion outcome  =%  for /f "tokens=2" %%? in ("%%!%%! 1 0") do (%\n%
        %= Switch - Setlocal / NOP                  =%    If %%~? EQU 1 SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion%\n%
        rem %= Output Dividing Line                     =%    ^>"%~f0:MenuMacro:$Data" (%\n%
        %= If Header Substitute Output substitution =%    If not "Header" == "%%!Menu.Hash%%!" (%\n%
                                    If Defined Menu_Div Echo(%%!Menu_Div%%!%\n%
                                    Echo(Header%\n%
                                  )%\n%
                                  If Defined Menu_Div Echo(%%!Menu_Div%%!%\n%
        %= Reset Menu.# index for Menu.Item[#]      =%    Set "Menu.#=0"%\n%
        %= Undefine choice command key list         =%    Set "Menu.Chars="%\n%
        %= Redirect output to ADS; For Each in List =%    For %%G in (%%!Menu{Args}%%!)Do (%\n%
        %= For Menu.Item Index value                =%      For %%i in (%%!Menu.#%%!)Do If not %%i GTR 35 (%\n%
        %= Build the Choice key list                =%        Set "Menu.Chars=%%!Menu.Chars%%!%%!Menu.Keys:~%%i,1%%!"%\n%
        %= Define Menu.Item array                   =%        Set "Menu.Item[%%!Menu.Keys:~%%i,1%%!]=%%~G"%\n%
        %= Assign String for safe output            =%        Set "Menu.Output=%%~G"%\n%
        %= Display as [key] Option String           =%        Echo([%%!Menu.Keys:~%%i,1%%!] %%!Menu.Output%%!%\n%
        %= Increment Menu.# Index var               =%        Set /A "Menu.#+=1"%\n%
        %= Close Menu.# expansion loop              =%      )%\n%
        %= Close Menu{Args} String loop             =%    ) %\n%
        rem %= Read output in from ADS to permit More   =%    More ^< "%~f0:MenuMacro:$Data"%\n%
        %= Output Dividing Line                     =%    If Defined Menu_Div Echo(%%!Menu_Div%%!%\n%
        %= Select option by character index         =%    For /f "delims=" %%o in ('%__APPDIR__%Choice.exe /N /C:%%!Menu.Chars%%!')Do For /f "tokens=1,2 delims=;" %%V in ("%%!Menu.Item[%%o]%%!;%%!Menu@%%o%%!")Do (%\n%
        %= Switch - Endlocal / NOP ; returnVars     =%      ( If %%~? EQU 1 EndLocal ) ^& (%\n%
        %= exit [sub]script w/out modifying option  =%        If /I "%%V" == "Exit" Exit /B 2%\n%
        %= Assign 'Menu{String}' w/literal string   =%        Set "Menu{String}=%%V"%\n%
        %= Assign 'Menu{key}' with key pressed      =%        Set "Menu{Key}=%%o"%\n%
        %= Assign 'Menu{Number} with list position  =%        Set "Menu{Number}=%%~W"%\n%
        %= Reset Menu Argument variable             =%        Set "Menu{Args}="%\n%
        %= Set errorlevel to match Menu{Number}     =%        CMD /C Exit %%~W%\n%
        %= Close Menu macro processing loops        =%  )  )  )%\n%
    )Else (%\n: Show Macro Help if no arguments supplied - will not display if expanded menu variable has trailing whitespace =%
        CLS%\n%
        Echo(Usage:%\n%
        Echo(%\n%
        Echo(%%Menu%%%\n%
        Echo(       Output this help info, Set Errorlevel 0%\n%
        Echo(%\n%
        Echo(%%Menu%% "DoubleQuoted List" "Of Options"%\n%
        Echo(       Output the Menu list, Take input%\n%
        Echo(%\n%
        Echo(%%Menu:Header=Your Custom Header%% "DoubleQuoted List" "Of Options"%\n%
        Echo(       Outputs substituted Header, Output Menu list; Take input%\n%
        Echo(%\n%
        Echo(Return Variables:%\n%
        Echo(       Menu{String}    : The literal String%\n%
        Echo(       Menu{Key}   : The Key Pressed%\n%
        Echo(       Menu{Number}    : The list position of the option as an Integer%\n%
        Echo(                 IE:   Option 1 = 1, Option A = 10%\n%
        Echo(                 Note: The Errorlevel is also set to this value%\n%
        Echo(%\n%
        Echo(  Note:      The number of options available is limited to 36.%\n%
        Echo(%\n%
        Echo(  Important: The following variable prefix is reserved: Menu%\n%
        Echo(%\n%
        Pause%\n%
        CLS%\n%
        %= If Menu expanded without Args Set Errorlevel 0 =%(Call )%\n%
    )%\n%
%= Capture Macro input - Options List       =%)Else Set Menu{Args}=^"
========================================== REM = Menu Macro Definition END

If Not "%~1" == "" Echo(%*|%SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /LI "/D Def Menu Load Menu Get" 2>&1 > nul && Exit /b 0
```