# Batch Random Charachters Err

Tags: batch-file

I was playing around with batch scripts on windows and I was trying to make a basic password generator.

`( Maximum setlocal recursion level reached. )`

My code :

```
@Echo Off
color 0a
set /P lengthnumberuser="What length do you want your password to be?   "
pause
cls

:code
Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set _RNDLength=16
set _Alphanumeric=ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789
set _Str=%_Alphanumeric%987654321
:_LenLoop
if NOT "%_Str:~18%"=="" SET _Str=%_Str:~9%& SET /A _Len+=9& GOTO :_LenLoop
set _tmp=%_Str:~9,1%
set /A _Len=_Len+_tmp
set _count=0
sET _RndAlphaNum=
:_loop
set /a _count+=1
sET _RND=%Random%
set /A _RND=_RND%%%_Len%
sET _RndAlphaNum=!_RndAlphaNum!!_Alphanumeric:~%_RND%,1!
if !_count! lss %_RNDLength% goto _loop
echo !_RndAlphaNum!
goto code
pause
```

Comment: move `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` out of the loop (best place would be as second line, right after `@echo off`)

Answer (score 1):

Just delete the `goto code` at the end of the your code.

See Here : [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37209098/9556248)