# Even distribution of random numbers in Windows batch

Tags: windows, batch-file, random, cmd

I want a random number in Windows batch.  Here's my command:

```
set /a "random_line=(%random%%%total)+1"
```

Is this going to give me an even distribution of random numbers?

**EDIT:**

I'd already looked at [How to use random in BATCH script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5777400/how-to-use-random-in-batch-script/5777608#5777608), and CherryDT's answer made me ask the question about even distribution:

> Note that this will not be uniformly distributed! Taking the 0~99
>   example, the numbers 0~67 will occur slightly more often than the
>   numbers 68~99 because 32767 modulo 100 is 67 and not 0 as it would
>   have to be for a uniform distribution. (This `%random% %%100` is no
>   magic syntax but actually `%random % %% 100` with one less space, where
>   the `%%` is just an escaped `%` which stands for modulo.)

So to clarify, will this give me uneven distribution?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5777608/1683264

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use random in BATCH script?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5777400/how-to-use-random-in-batch-script)

Comment: You asked, ***"is this going to give me an even distribution?"***, and also ***"will this give me uneven distribution?"***, so the clear answer is **Yes** and **No**, but not necessarily in that order. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer to your question: **No**, your calculation will not give you a uniform distribution.

Long answer, with a bit of imagination of what you want to achieve,

`%random%` will give you a uniform distribution

but your code is not probably doing what you pretend.

Because the `%RANDOM%` dynamic variable generates a random integer from 0 to 32767 both inclusive.

If you want to transform it to a uniform integer distribution between `1` and `%total%` you need this calculation

```
SET /a random_line=(%RANDOM%*%total%/32768)+1
```

Comment: Let's say %random% = 32767 and %total% = 100.  That means (32767*100/32768)+1 = 100.996948242.  Will this round up to 101?  Because it cannot be higher than 100.

Comment: Answered my own question.  It will always round down.  Thanks.

Comment: @grgoelyk This is integer math, there is no rounding but truncating

Comment: Okay, makes sense.