# Trying to generate random number between 65 and 67 in a batch file

Tags: batch-file

This always generates 83, which is neither random nor within the desired range:

```
set /a result=(%random%*67/32768)+65
```

This generates random numbers but still not within the range I want:

```
set /a result=%random% %% 67+65
```

This generates random numbers, all of which seem negative and cover a vast range:

```
set /a result=%random% %% 67-65
```

These are the options I've found via Googling.

Comment: I think you are basically looking for a solution that yields `(random mod 3) + 65`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the command line it is:

```
set /a _test=(%RANDOM% % 3) + 65
```

In a batch file it is:

```
set /a _test=(%RANDOM% %% 3) + 65
```

Comment: Works perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

For your specific case of 65-67, you can use:

```
SET /A result=%RANDOM% * 3 / 32768 + 65
```

The general formula is:

```
%RANDOM% * (%MAX% - %MIN% + 1) / 32768 + %MINIMUM%
```

Adapted from a comment in [How to use random in BATCH script?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5777400/2441).

Comment: Yeah, I think that's what I was going for in my first example but I messed up and put "max" instead of "range". But I've run it several times now and generated 65 every time, same as my example always generated 83.

Comment: Are you doing this inside a loop? You probably need to add `SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION` and use `!RANDOM!` instead of `%RANDOM%`.

Comment: What's the difference? But no, it's not in a loop.

Comment: You would need delayed expansion enabled if doing it inside a loop. Can you post your complete code or at least more of it for better context?

Comment: It seems it is generating a random result, but it changes so infrequently as to be meaningless. The %RANDOM% is always random, but the /3/32768+65 keeps ending up at the same number for several minutes at a time. jwdonahue's answer gets me much more random results.

Comment: That's certainly strange and I can't replicate that result. I didn't do a statistical analysis, but using my formula and the one from jwdonahue's answer generate about the same distribution of numbers for me.