# Why do the IF statements cause batch file to exit?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I have tried to make the code pick a random number 1-5 and it would then choose a random area in the game. The problem is that it keeps exiting whenever it executes. It ignores also the `x` between the `%place%` variable.

```
pause
set place=%random% %% 5
timeout 1
if x%place%x==1 goto cave
if x%place%x==2 goto plains
if x%place%x==3 goto swamp
if x%place%x==4 goto volcano
if x%place%x==5 goto fail
:cave
echo You went for a crusade and ended up in a cave.
pause
:plains
echo You went for a crusade and found a plains biome.
pause
:swamp
echo You went for a crusade and ventured into a swamp.
pause
:volcano
echo You went for a crusade and somehow ended up on a volcano.
pause
:fail
echo Your boat sank and you survived. You lost 5 coins.
pause
```

Comment: Your syntax for getting a random number is off. See [How to use random in BATCH script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5777400/how-to-use-random-in-batch-script). Also of note: your `x`s are not going to work and you will output all text from the first one down as there are no `goto` or other means of exiting.

Comment: You are comparing `x#x` with `#`, which is never true, and the number in `place` is in the range from `0` to `4`. Anyway, even if your `if` conditions worked, execution would walk through all following sections; for instance, when you jump to `:cave`, after having confirmed the `pause` prompt, execution just continues at `:plains` and so on, unless you put `goto :somewhere` at the end of each section…

Answer (score 1):

Your `set` statement needs the `/a` switch because you are trying to do math.  Also you need to add one to the result, because right now you are getting a random number in the range of 0-4, and your `if` statements are numbered 1-5.  Also I know you said to ignore the x's, but they need to go if you want your program to work.  Here is an edited copy of your program:

```
set /a place = %RANDOM% %% 5 + 1
timeout 1
if %place% equ 1 goto cave
if %place% equ 2 goto plains
if %place% equ 3 goto swamp
if %place% equ 4 goto volcano
if %place% equ 5 goto fail
:cave
echo You went for a crusade and ended up in a cave.
pause
:plains
echo You went for a crusade and found a plains biome.
pause
:swamp
echo You went for a crusade and ventured into a swamp.
pause
:volcano
echo You went for a crusade and somehow ended up on a volcano.
pause
:fail
echo Your boat sank and you survived. You lost 5 coins.
pause
```

Comment: For numeric comparisons I would use `if %place% equ 1` (although it makes no difference in this particular situation)…

Comment: @aschipfl Well, in this case a string comparison with operator `==` is much faster than an integer comparison with operator `EQU`. `if %place% == 1 goto cave` runs `strcmp()` which has to compare just one or two bytes for the result. The usage of `if %place% EQU 1 goto cave` results in running two times `strtol()` and then comparing the two signed long integer values. That takes much more CPU cycles, but is nevertheless finished in a few microseconds. The fastest solution would be not using `if` at all by using something like `goto Place%place%` and using the labels `Place1`, `Place2`, ...

Comment: @Mofi Thank you for your insights.  You are correct that `==` is faster than `EQU`, however, I personally think `EQU` makes for clearer code.  Both ways will work, so I'm not going to flip my answer back and forth.  Your alternate solution using a single `goto` statement will also work, but it makes the labels less readable.  The intent of this question was just to stop the `if` statements from crashing the program.  Again, thank you for the in-depth comparisons.

Answer (score 0):

The first mistake is already on the line:

```
set place=%random% %% 5
```

This line assigns a **string** to environment variable `place` which consists of

- a random decimal number in range 0 to 32767,
- a space character,
- a percent sign,
- a space character and
- the number 5.

As a result the first `if` command line is after processing before execution for example:

```
if x20934 % 5x==1 goto cave
```

The Windows command processor exits batch file processing with the error message:

> % was unexpected at this time.

That is a pretty clear error message on [debugging the batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42448601/3074564). The first argument of command **IF** is `x20934` and so the Windows command processor expects next either the string comparison operator `==` or with command extensions enabled as by default one of the operators `EQU`, `NEQ`, `LSS`, `LEQ`, `GTR`, `GEQ` which are mainly for comparing two 32-bit signed integer values, but can be used also for string comparisons.

Please read the answer on [Symbol equivalent to NEQ, LSS, GTR, etc. in Windows batch files](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47386323/3074564) for full details how Windows command processor does a string or integer comparison.

So it is first necessary to correct the command line which should evaluate an **a**rithmetic expression and assign the result as **string** to environment variable `place`.

```
set /A place=%RANDOM% %% 5 + 1
```

Then it would be possible to use **IF** conditions with either operator `==` or `EQU` to evaluate the result.

The usage of string comparison operator `==` would be faster in this case on which it is 100% sure that `place` is a string with first character being `1`, `2`, `3`, `4` or `5` (with decimal code value 49 to 53) and second character is the terminating null (with decimal code value 0). So the function [strcmp](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcmp/) used by `cmd.exe` returns the integer result already after first or second character (byte) compare.

```
set /A place=%RANDOM% %% 5 + 1
if %place% == 1 goto cave
if %place% == 2 goto plains
if %place% == 3 goto swamp
if %place% == 4 goto volcano
if %place% == 5 goto fail
```

It would be also possible to use `EQU` as operator. But in this case both strings are first converted with function [strtol](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/strtol/) to 32-bit signed integer values which are next compared using an integer comparison. That requires much more CPU cycles to accomplish the comparison.

```
set /A place=%RANDOM% %% 5 + 1
if %place% EQU 1 goto cave
if %place% EQU 2 goto plains
if %place% EQU 3 goto swamp
if %place% EQU 4 goto volcano
if %place% EQU 5 goto fail
```

The user running the batch file will not see a difference. The processors in PCs are nowadays so fast that the much more CPU cycles needed for the execution of the two `strtol` in comparison to execution of single `strcmp` is just a few microseconds.

The batch file execution efficiency can be increased even more by avoiding the five **IF** conditions completely because of the Windows command processor has to do in worst case five times:

- Open the batch file.
- Set file read position to byte offset of end of last read.
- Read the bytes from batch file up to next line-feed.
- Preprocess the command line to find out if more lines need to be read.
- Remember current byte position in batch file.
- Close the batch file.
- Process the command line completely and execute it.

The **IF** conditions can be avoided by using appropriate labels and use just command **GOTO** with a label depending on environment variable `place`:

```
@echo off
set /A place=%RANDOM% %% 5
goto Place%place%

:Place0 - cave
echo You went for a crusade and ended up in a cave.& echo(& pause
rem More commands for cave.
exit /B

:Place1 - plains
echo You went for a crusade and found a plains biome.& echo(& pause
rem More commands for plains.
exit /B

:Place2 - swamp
echo You went for a crusade and ventured into a swamp.& echo(& pause
rem More commands for swamp.
exit /B

:Place3 - volcano
echo You went for a crusade and somehow ended up on a volcano.& echo(& pause
rem More commands for volcano.
exit /B

:Place4 - fail
echo Your boat sank and you survived. You lost 5 coins.& echo(& pause
```

The Windows command processor interprets just the string after `:` up to first delimiter character as label. So it is possible to use the labels as shown above to know which **Place**`x` label is for which place because of the string after the space is ignored by Windows command processor.

The arithmetic expression results in a value in range `0-4` assigned as string to environment variable `place` which is concatenated with the string `Place` on next command line to the label name to be processed by **GOTO** to continue batch file processing on the line below that label.

To understand the commands used and how they work, open a [command prompt](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/10-ways-to-open-the-command-prompt-in-windows-10/) window, execute there the following commands, and read the displayed help pages for each command, entirely and carefully.

- `echo /?`
- `exit /?`
- `goto /?`
- `pause /?`
- `rem /?`
- `set /?`

See also [single line with multiple commands](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25344009/3074564) for an explanation of operator `&`.